# How can I simulate a click on an JS Audio element?

Tags: javascript, audio

Suppose I have an  element. How can simulate a play click? a pause click? etc.

```
<audio controls>
<source src="song.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

Comment: And your coding attempt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the `.play()` and `.pause()` functions:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <audio controls>
        <source id="audio_player" src="https://file-examples.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/file_example_MP3_1MG.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
    </audio>
    <script>
        document.getElementById("audio_player").play();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks. The only problem is that I have to play the audio manually before using this. Otherwise, running it as a local html I get "Autoplay is only allowed when approved by the user, the site is activated by the user, or media is muted. "         AND
                  "NotAllowedError: The play method is not allowed by the user agent or the platform in the current context, possibly because the user denied permission."

Comment: The audio tag need the `id="audio_player"` not the source. I updated my answer. Check if it is still not working.

Comment: if you're trying to get around the annoyance prevention via human interaction event sourcing, you can't.